# Datetime conversion error in SSIS from US date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I've got an issue with my SSIS dataflow. I'm extracting data from SalesForce Marketing Cloud. In one of the data extensions, there's a date field (in US format).
The problem is that when the data is extracted, the conversion is wrong. Sometimes it inverts the month and the day, and sometimes it doesn't.

[Source:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb7Jk.jpg)

[Destination:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztYrH.jpg)

Does anyone know for what reason, it converts the data wrongly? And what I should do to correct it?

PS: when I perform a CONVERT(DATETIME, [CreatedDate], 101) it works, but if there's a way to do it directly in SSIS, it would be nice

Thanks.

Comment: what is the datatype of this column ? The database does not stores the dates in any format, they are stored as a numeric value. The format they show up on your screen is depending on the client and the culture of the OS only

Comment: In the Source, the datatype is Datetime (US), in the Destination, it is Datetime as well (EU)

Comment: There is no datetime (US) or datetime (EU) There is only Datetime in sql server (and datetime2 and date offcourse). What you see is not how it is in your database, its your client and/or OS that is showing it like that

Comment: What I mean is that the date is stored under US format in the source Database (MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM instead of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (standard Sql Server))

Comment: No they are not. The database does not uses any format to store date value. They are stored as a numeric value without any format what so ever. The format that you see on your screens are done by the software, not the database

Comment: Ok, they are not then. I still don't get your point in how this helps with the question.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` datatype format depends on your computer culture. if you want to unite the `DateTime` format as the same value. you need to use [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function

Then your convert type might be string otherwise, the result will be the same depends on your computer culture.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) + ' '  + convert(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 14)
```

there is a simpler way use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss')
```

Comment: Yes of course, I understand. SSIS also converts the field in normal date format (YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS). The problem is that it converts it wrongly (cf. my screenshots)

Comment: @Vladimir I add more explain and example your can try it

Comment: Thank you D-Shih, it's very clear. But actually I already tried this and I know this works. What I would like is not an Sql request but SSIS to do it dorectly and correctly (not like in my screenshots)